# How to duplicate a row if a condition is matched?

Tags: pandas, database, date

I have the following dataset

```
    trade_id    start_date  end_date    factset_entity_id   product_id  product_name    l6_id   multi_assign_flag
0   100000191   2017    NaT 0711GY-E    99996362    Fan Milk - FanYogo  5.015152e+11    0.0
1   100000193   2017    2018    0711GY-E    99996413    Fan Milk - FanDango/Frozen FanDango 5.015151e+11    0.0
2   100000193   2018    2022    0711GY-E    99996413    Fan Milk - FanDango 5.015151e+11    0.0
3   100000193   2022    NaT 0711GY-E    99996413    Fan Milk - FanDango 5.015151e+11    0.0
4   100000231   2016    2018    05NC3S-E    59979529    Ci:z Holdings - Dr. Ci:Labo 5.020102e+11    1.0
```

My goal is to duplicate the rows in which start_*date and end*_date are different, for instance

```
1   100000193   2017    2018    0711GY-E    99996413    Fan Milk - FanDango/Frozen FanDango 5.015151e+11    0.0
```

should be

```
2017    100000193   0711GY-E    99996413    Fan Milk - FanDango/Frozen FanDango 5.015151e+11    0.0
2018    100000193   0711GY-E    99996413    Fan Milk - FanDango/Frozen FanDango 5.015151e+11    0.0
```

Do you have any idea about what could I do here without using loops? Thanks

I try to do it using simple loops and it's fine, but it's slow. I wonder if there are shortcuts in pandas that ease it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following toy dataframe in which rows 0 and 2 have different start and end dates:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "trade_id": [100000191, 100000192, 100000193, 100000194, 100000231],
        "start_date": [2017, 2017, 2018, 2022, 2018],
        "end_date": [None, 2017, 2022, 2022, 2018],
        "factset_entity_id": [
            "0711GY-E",
            "0711GY-E",
            "0711GY-E",
            "0711GY-E",
            "05NC3S-E",
        ],
        "product_id": [99996362, 99996413, 99996414, 99996415, 59979529],
    }
)
```

Here is one way to do it using [pd.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```py
df = pd.concat([df, df.loc[df["start_date"] != df["end_date"], :]]).sort_index()
```

Then, you can see that rows 0 and 2 are now duplicated:

```py
print(df)
# Output
    trade_id  start_date  end_date factset_entity_id  product_id
0  100000191        2017       NaN          0711GY-E    99996362
0  100000191        2017       NaN          0711GY-E    99996362
1  100000192        2017    2017.0          0711GY-E    99996413
2  100000193        2018    2022.0          0711GY-E    99996414
2  100000193        2018    2022.0          0711GY-E    99996414
3  100000194        2022    2022.0          0711GY-E    99996415
4  100000231        2018    2018.0          05NC3S-E    59979529
```

Comment: That's much more elegant to what I have done indeed. Thank you very much!